# Create a custom InputType

Tags: android, android-edittext

Is it possible to create a custom InputType for the Android keyboard to use?

I want to make it so the keyboard shows the number pad first and then after a user types in a float or an integer followed by a space I want it to switch to the default alpha keyboard.

I tried using a TextWatcher instance, but this seems buggy on anything above 2.0 (sometimes it would lose a character, this doesn't happen on 1.6 or below).

Any ideas?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Have you looked at the 'Soft Keyboard' sample? http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SoftKeyboard/index.html

Comment: I don't really want to make a whole new input type, I just want to change the way the default keyboard behaves. I'm not sure if that's possible though. I just want it to start on the number pad and then switch to the alpha keyboard after space is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.

I haven't done it myself, but the evidence is in apps that serve as input types.  Look up apps such as Swype and 8pen; they serve as different input types, with Swype building on a keyboard similar to the default and 8pen providing a different input UI altogether.

Comment: I didn't want to create an entirely new input, I just want to change the way the default keyboard behaves. Thanks though, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That's still possible.  With those apps still as evidence, here's what they did.

1. Looked at the input being used.
2. Replaced it with their own.

With you, it sounds like what you need to do is:

1. Look at the input being used (the default keyboard).
2. See how it's arranged.
3. Change the arrangements and behavior so that what you want is achieved.

It's still possible and probably available to you.  You'll need to get into the source code for Android.  The first place I'd look is developer.android.com.  Good luck!